# Setting SURF algorithm parameters in OpenCV Android or Java

Tags: android, opencv, surf

A question about the object matching in Android-Opencv.

As I cannot find any sample code of using SURF in Android platform. I would like to refer to some sample codes in C++.

But I have no idea about how to set the threshold value of SURF FeatureDetector in Android. Anyone with experience of Android-Opencv can help ?

Thanks a lot..!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think is possible right now, but there is a workaround I'm using. You have to create a text file containig the parameters and then read the file with the method inside your feature detector. Something like this:

```
File tempDir = context.getCacheDir();
File tempFile = File.createTempFile("config", ".yml", tempDir);

String settings = "%YAML:1.0\nhessianThreshold: 8000.\noctaves: 3\noctaveLayers: 4\nupright: 0\n";

FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(tempFile, false);
writer.write(settings);
writer.close();

SURFDetector.read(tempFile.getPath());
```

Hope this will help you!

Comment: Yes i can confirm that currently this is the appropriate approach to do it in OpenCV4Android.

Comment: are `\noctaves` and `\noctaveLayers` typos? shouldn't it be `\nnOctaves` and `\nnOctaveLayers` since `\n` is for next line? per http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/nonfree/doc/feature_detection.html#int nOctaves