# Setting hessian threshold in android

Tags: java, android, opencv, code-conversion

How to set hessian threshold value for surf detectror in opencv library.

In C++. I can set it as:

```
int minHessian = 100;
SurfFeatureDetector detector( minHessian );**
```

But in android, surf detector is created as:

```
FeatureDetector surf=FeatureDetector.create(FeatureDetector.SURF);
```

So, how does I set the value of min hessian in android.

Make note that, SURF is not available in newer versions of opencv library, I am using `opencv 2.4.1`, so that I can do surf detection in android.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android-Opencv: Procedure of using SURF in opencv](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7410852/android-opencv-procedure-of-using-surf-in-opencv)