# how to set filtering parameters in "simplebolbdetector" of opencv 2.4.5's "featuredetector"

Tags: android, opencv

```
private FeatureDetector  PupilBolbDetector;
public FeatureDetector BlobDetector()
{
    PupilBolbDetector = FeatureDetector.create(FeatureDetector.SIMPLEBLOB);
    return PupilBolbDetector;
}
```

How to set filtering parameters such as "thresholdStep", "minThreshold" of simpleblobdetector in android opencv 2.4.5? I want to use simpleblobdetector for pupil detection. Forgoing code is my method to generate simpleblobdetector, and all the parameters can be found in the guidance of Opencv as following code:

```
class SimpleBlobDetector : public FeatureDetector
{
    public:
    struct Params
{
    Params();
    float thresholdStep;
    float minThreshold;
    float maxThreshold;
    size_t minRepeatability;
    float minDistBetweenBlobs;

    bool filterByColor;
    uchar blobColor;

    bool filterByArea;
    float minArea, maxArea;

    bool filterByCircularity;
    float minCircularity, maxCircularity;

    bool filterByInertia;
    float minInertiaRatio, maxInertiaRatio;

    bool filterByConvexity;
    float minConvexity, maxConvexity;
};

SimpleBlobDetector(const SimpleBlobDetector::Params &parameters = SimpleBlobDetector::Params());

    protected:
    ...
};
```

Comment: you want to do that from c++ (jni) or from java ?

Comment: from java. It an android application.

Comment: oh dear, seems it's not possible. (thought for a moment it would work through the Algorithm get/set interface, like in python, but no way in java )

Comment: Berak, do you have any advice i want to use simpleblobdetector in my android application?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setting SURF algorithm parameters in OpenCV Android or Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7410852/setting-surf-algorithm-parameters-in-opencv-android-or-java)

Comment: Check this post, the solution should apply to you: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7410852/1085483